# How to use javascript variable with ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

Got a bit of a problem, and yes, I know that I did it the wrong way around to start with, but that will be fixed in the next version.

So have finally managed to get a variable from express on the backend to the javascript (stored in users in the below example). And it works so far, the console.log will write the correct value.

How do I now use that value as a filter, tried just set '_id': users, but that does not work, if I change it to the actual value. It all works fine (oh, and its in jade)

```
  script(type='text/javascript').
    var users = !{JSON.stringify(canid)};
    console.log("got the follwoing :" + users);


  ul.profilelist(ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: {'_id': users }")
     li
        img.sumpic(src="../{{profile.img}}")
```

Comment: it should be `ul.profilelist(ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: {'_id': "+users+" }")` as it not inside angular scope..otherwise you can do `$scope.users = !{JSON.stringify(canid)};`

Comment: Can't get either of those to work:( Tried ul.profilelist(ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: {'_id': "+users+"  }")

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: If I set try to do $scope in the java script it blows up, if I put it in the angular script it does not load. If I do "+users+ nothing in the console at all

Comment: try this `ul.profilelist('ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter: {\'_id\': users }')` i think you forgot add quotes to `ng-repeat`

Comment: That gave me a pretty spectacular error message :) Is there not a " missing from the above line?

Comment: Tried to create this function as well. `var app = this;  app.getcan = function (canid) { $scope.canid = canid; console.log("Now we have set canid to " + $scope.canid); }` then calling app. But javascript does not have access to app.

Comment: Can i know what `profilelist` mehod contains

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, in the end I decided to bite the bullet and just change to using single page angular instead. Will see how that works out

Comment: Cool..After getting the solution add it as answer..So that it'll will be helpful for other. Thanks.

Comment: Alas, I think the answer will be, just (don't) do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I really tried to figure this out, and while it might be possible, it is an absolute nightmare. 
I ended up decided that it was easier to use internal routing and write it as it is suppose to, even if I love being a rebel, I really could not find a smooth way of getting the data from the backend all the way to html, javascript then over to Angular. I know this isn't a answer to my question, but I think it might be the best way.